# Ajax запрос в контролер при смене выбора в DropDownList

Tags: c#, jquery, mvc

привет есть ajax запрос на jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("#drop-down-type").change(function () {
        $.post(
            "Home/CurentDivision",
            {
                Type: $(this).val(),
            },
            success
        );
$("#drop-down-division-current").empty();
        function success(data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                $("#drop-down-division-current").append("<option value=" + val + ">" + val + "</option>");
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Метод в контролере

```
[HttpPost]
        public string[] CurentDivision(string Type)
        {
            var T = Structure.Divisions.Where(g => g.DivisionType == Type).Select(g => g.DivisionName).ToArray();
            ///
            ///
            ///
            return T;
        }
```

Запрос проходит и возвращает данные. Но проблема в том что как их обработать и записать в другой выпадающий список.

UPDATE
Получилось сделать так

```
$(function() {
    $("#drop-down-type").change(function () {
        $.get(
            "Home/CurentDivision",
            {
                Type: $(this).val(),
            },
            success
        );
        $("#drop-down-division-current").empty();
        function success(data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                $("#drop-down-division-current").append("<option value=" + val + ">" + val.DivisionName + "</option>");
            });
            //data = JSON.parse(data);
            //for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //    $("#drop-down-division-current").append("<option value=val>" + data[i] + "</option>");
            //}
        }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

C#

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult CurentDivision(string Type)
        {
            var T = Structure.Divisions.Where(g => g.DivisionType == Type).Select(g => g);
            ///
            ///
            ///
            return Json(T,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Оставлю место для ответа может подскажет как реализовать на основе первого варианта

Comment: HttpPost возвращает string[], a не JsonResult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод в контролере:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CurrentDivision(string Type)
{
    var T = Structure.Divisions.Where(g => g.DivisionType == Type).Select(g => g.DivisionName).ToArray();
    // или
    // var T = Structure.Divisions.Where(g => g.DivisionType == Type).Select(g => g);
    // Не уверен, что вам нужно выбирать
    return Json(T);
}
```